# Can I make a GET request to list multiple cities by multiples ID's with geocoder?

Tags: here-api

With this GET request I can show information about one city

> geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?level=city&mode=retrieveAreas&app_id=*APP_ID*&app_code=*APP_CODE*&**LocationId=*LOCATION_ID***

But how can I make a single request to GET multiples cities by multiples LocationId's?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have multiple address of different cities for which the geo-coordinates need to be determined ?

Comment: I have only an Array of ID's  (LocationId's), I want to show information (city name, state, country, etc) of all cities of this array with a single request

Comment: Unfortunately there is no API by which you can pass array of locationId's in a single request. You have to make request one by one. https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-locationid

Answer (score 0):

Currently HERE API does not support passing array into location Id. You have to make the single request at a time but we can recommend this to our team as enhancement feature request.

```
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json
?locationid=NT_5mGkj3z90Fbj4abzMbUE4C_xA
&jsonattributes=1
&gen=9
&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Hope this helps!